# How can I vendor a 3rd party js lib via a script tag in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, configuration, plaid

I'm trying to integrate Plaid with an Ember app and am following the instructions on their site. It should be simple, the instructions say to just add

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js" />
```

and it'll give you a `Plaid` class that can be used to interface with Plaid.

That works fine, but ideally I'd like to vendor this script and import it in a service where I can do my work on it. This does not work out of the box. Unfortunately, this script *relies on being embedded with a script tag.* If you unminify the thing, there's a line where it very explicitly tries to find the script tag that embedded it, and it throws an error if it can't find it.

From the unminified code:

```
findScriptTag: function() {
  for (var t = document.getElementsByTagName("script"), n = 0, e = t.length; n < e; n += 1)
    if (/link-initialize(\..*?)?\.js$/.test(t[n].src)) return t[n];
  throw new Error("Failed to find script")
```

My question is, can I configure ember to load certain vendored scripts separately from everything else, in its own script tag? I'd also need to control the name of the file, since the above expects the name to be link-initialize.js. Or is there another way around this?

My current workaround is to just add the script tag to index.html, but I'd really like to be able to say `import Plaid from 'plaid';`, or something close to that... Unit testing is impossible without this.

---

To clarify: As far as I know, **there is no npm package for this**.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/plaid is a backend lib that **does not handle** embedding Plaid on the page. It is entirely different from the link-initialize.js script the plaid docs say to embed.

Comment: This is going to take you pretty far outside the beaten path for Ember. Could you use https://github.com/plaid/plaid-node instead?

Comment: I'm aware. :) And no, that's a lib for dealing with their api, and is meant to be run by the server. You can see that setup for it takes a secret key. I've already got that side of things working correctly in a rails backend anyway. My question is strictly about loading the script on the frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in the `public` folder. This will ensure `ember-cli` will copy it into your build output 1:1. Then add the script tag like
`<script src="/link-initialize.js" />` to your `index.html` and it should work.

If you insist to keep the file in the `vendor` folder you can use broccoli `Funnel` and `MergeTrees` inside `ember-cli-build.js` to copy it to the `dist` folder and use the same script tag.

---

about the import:
you can create a `vendor-shim`. Just do `ember generate vendor-shim plain`. In the vendor shim just return the global variable provided by `link-initialize.js`. Then you can `import` this.

Comment: That did it. Feeling really dumb for not thinking to just put it in public/. Was digging into vendor shims and that's definitely the way to go. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to achieve this with [ember-auto-import](https://github.com/ef4/ember-auto-import).

Then you should be able to just install [Plaid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plaid) from npm and import it wherever you need it in your ember application.

Comment: Per my response to @jrjohnson, that lib does not do what I want. The stuff I'm trying to import is not included in the [plaid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plaid) package, because that package only handles interfacing with the Plaid API. I have not found any npm package that loads the link-initialize script, hence my attempts to vendor the script. If you find one, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: I see. Then the public folder should work great for you. Thanks for the taking the time to further explain.